# Filter Many to Many field with multiple values using django-filter

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have two models: `Ticket` and `User`. They have a many to many relationship where many users can be assigned to a ticket. I am using the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) package to filter the ticket model. I can successfully filter the ticket by a single user. For example:

```
http://localhost:8000/tickets?users=1
```

But I'm trying to filter the ticket by multiple user assigned to the ticket.

```
http://localhost:8000/tickets?users__in=1,2
```

I tried using the `__in` operator, but I got this error:

```
'list' object has no attribute 'split'


/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django_filters/widgets.py, line 213, in value_from_datadict
```

Here's my View code:

```py
class TicketViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Ticket.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = {
        "status": ["in", "exact"],
        "users": ["in", "exact"]
    }
```

How can I filter the ticket by the users filed by multiple values?

Here's the Ticket model:

```py
class Ticket:
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=7, default='new')
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: Can you add the `Ticket` model here?

Comment: @Metalgear, I've updated the question with the`Ticket` model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an issue similar to your case: https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/1103

You might also wanna try:

```
http://localhost:8000/tickets?users=1&users=2
```